# How do I fetch the latest video captured?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, photo, avkit

How can I fetch the URL of the latest video that I captured? **I don't want to fetch all of the videos, just the last one.**
*Here the code how I'm saving a video, I'm creating a saving function which helps me to save a video to a custom photos album and then I call this function:*

```
// Saving function
func saveVideo(vurl: URL) {

    if assetCollection == nil {
        return   // If there was an error upstream, skip the save.
            print("assetCollection = nil")
    }

    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        let assetChangeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: vurl)
        let assetPlaceholder = assetChangeRequest!.placeholderForCreatedAsset
        let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: self.assetCollection)
        albumChangeRequest!.addAssets([assetPlaceholder] as NSFastEnumeration)
        print("TEST----------: \(albumChangeRequest!)")
    }, completionHandler: nil)
}
// Saving proccess
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    print("Got a video")

    if let pickedVideo:URL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL {
        // Save video to the custom photo album

        print(pickedVideo)

        if mainrepo == "" {
            print("saving")
            CustomPhotoAlbum.sharedInstance.saveVideo(vurl: pickedVideo)

            // saving video url to core data
            let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

            let saver = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Repository", into: context)

            let date = Date()
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
            let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
            let result = formatter.string(from: date)
            print("time - \(hour):\(minutes)")
            print("date - \(result)")

            saver.setValue("\(pickedVideo)", forKey: "url")
            saver.setValue("\(hour):\(minutes)", forKey: "time")
            saver.setValue(result, forKey: "date")
            saver.setValue("...", forKey: "comment")

            appDelegate.saveContext()
            print("saved")
        }

    }
```

Comment: Where you store your video? If you are storing video in document directory, you can fetch it with stored name and directory path.

Comment: @A.H.Nuri I store the videos in the custom album in photos

Comment: You have the URL in `pickedVideo`. That is the last video you saved.

Comment: @rmaddy, this video URL is incorrect, it's a temporary url, when the video is saved, the url is changed

Comment: Can somebody help me with this?